# laravel auth testing without Authenticatable User

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-testing

I'm newbie on testing so I want to create a auth testing but in project I don't use laravel Models but I'm using own methods for auth because of started project too long ago. TestCase class has actingAs method but i don't use it so i can not test user auth and even more i don't know how can i test the panel ?

I post the user email and password with JSON and then user redirect to auth page. I have only laravel_session cookie.

Can I use the cookie for testing after auth ? How can I access the cookie and Do I have to send it with in header ?